# SELECT on two other queries in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, select

So, lets say I want to do something like:

```
SELECT Query1.a, 
       Query2.b 
FROM   (
           SELECT q as a 
           FROM   somewhere
       ), 
       (   
           SELECT g as b 
           FROM   elsewhere
       )
where  Query 1 is 
       (
           SELECT q as a 
           FROM   somewhere
       ) 
       and Query2 is 
       (
           SELECT g as b 
           FROM   elsewhere
       )
```

So, i want to select from two other select statements.

Query 1 produces a table

```
a

value1
```

Query 2 produces a table

```
b

value 2
```

And Query 3 (the outer select statement) produces

```
a                   b


value 1            value 2
```

So, essentially, two result tables are combined as columns and not as rows.

Thank you, if you have any hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically have your solution.  You are only missing the names of your queries, so do like this:

```
SELECT Query1.a, 
       Query2.b 
FROM   (
           SELECT q as a 
           FROM   somewhere
       ) Query1, 
       (   
           SELECT g as b 
           FROM   elsewhere
       ) Query2
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear how you need to connect different rows from tables but it can be something like this:

```
select query1.a,
       query2.b
FROM
(select q as a, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY q) as RN from a) Query1

FULL JOIN 
(select q as b, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY q) as RN from b) Query2
ON Query1.RN=Query2.RN
```

[SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a0839/5)

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is a bit off the SQL charts, but in essence ritgh:

It is possible to do a subquery:

```
select A.field from (select field from a_table) A;
```

It is essential that you name your query, if you want to use it in the select or where clauses.

And even possible to combine them like regular tables:

```
select A.field, B.other_field from (select field from table1) A, (select other_field from table2) B;
```

It is also possible to do al kind of where, grouping and sorting stuff on it, but not needed in your case.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is what you're looking for:

```
SELECT query1.a, query2.b
FROM 
  (SELECT q as a FROM somewhere) query1,
  (SELECT g as b FROM elsewhere) query2
```

Here is a [SQLFiddle to test the query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/df4f7/1)